# Removing a grid from an image

Tags: gimp, png, filter

I'm doing some image processing to detect bubbles in oil. One of the filters I use creates a grid in my image. 
[image: OilGrid]

If you look closely at the image you can see horizontal and vertical lines through the image forming a grid.

Does anyone know of a way to remove the grid (say by adjusting contrast)without loosing the other image details. I will always know the exact location of the grid.

It would be nice if a program like GIMP could do this.

Comment: Oddly, what I see are tiny "boxes" slightly gradient-ed. Not familiar with Gimp as such, but I guess Gimp would have the Photoshop equivalent of (filter) Despeckle, Dust and scratches, Reduce noise. Try searching for these equivalents. It might be a little extreme sport playing with this, so keep an eye on your oil bubbles.

Comment: The "grid" seems to be a result of broken pixels due to a low resolution image. The best you could do would be to target the areas you do NOT want to retain and blur them. I can't comment on how to do that with GIMP.

Comment: If you were wondering, the grid is introduced as a result of a background subtraction algorithm I'm using 
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/signal-separation-algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you source image is tiled as if a scanner stitched small tiles together. The steps outlined below for **Gimp** help to reduce these tiles but this will be a lossy process.

#### Image structure

Small detail of the original image adjusted for black and white levels with *"Colors > Levels.."* tool reveals the tiling artifact:

[image]

Unfortunately the border of each tile has great variance to it's neighbour making it nearly impossible to un-tile the image without a loss of details in the remaining image.

#### Gaussian Blur

The best results may be obtained with a Gaussian blur, as each tile itself is somewhat blurred as well.

[image]

This detail was blurred with Gaussian blur at 14 pixels (*"Filters > Blur > Gaussian Blur..."*).

There still is some tiling to be seen at tiles with a high contrast to it's neigbour. To further reduce this higher values of blur are needed. But these will then further reduce other details of the image.

#### Contrast Enhancement

We then may again adjust the black and white levels with the *"Color > Levels..."* tool until the resulting contrast was acceptable.

[image]